# How to handle embedded json in Sails js

Tags: javascript, express, sails.js

Is there a way to create a related object from embedded json in a sails.js controller?

In the contoller for the class that is being created, I need to create a related record in a different class and include the id of the parent record that was just created.

The data for the "child" record is embedded in the json that the parent record is being created from.  The database in use is Mongo so it does not enforce relatioships.

How can I create these related objects?

Any examples for reference would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I've implemented the changes in the first Answer and am now getting the error "[TypeError: Cannot call method 'all' of undefined]"

Any ideas?

Edited to add code:

PurchaseInfo Model

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

parent_account:{
    type:'string'
},

  purchase_date:{
      type:'datetime'
  },

  product:{
      type:'string'
  },

  subscription_length:{
      type:'integer'
  },

  renewal_date:{
      type:'date'
  },

  users_authorized:{
      type:'integer'
  },

  users_activated:{
      type:'integer'
  },

  company_name:{
      type:'string'
  },

  company_contact:{
      type:'string'
  },

  company_email:{
      type:'string',
      required:true,
      email:true
  },

  company_phone:{
      type:'string'
  },

  intended_use:{
      type:'string'
  },

  // reference to company
  company:{
      collection: 'company',
      via:'purchaser'
  }
}

};
```

Company Model

```
module.exports = {


attributes: {

company_name:{
    type:'string',
    required:'true'
},

  main_addr1:{
      type:'string',
      required:'true'
  },

  main_addr2:{
      type:'string',
      required:'true'
  },

  main_city:{
      type:'string',
      required:'true'
  },

  main_state:{
      type:'string',
      required:'true'
  },

  main_zip:{
      type:'string',
      required:'true'
  },

  main_country:{
      type:'string',
      required:'true'
  },

  mailing_same_as_main:{
      type:'boolean'
  },

  mailing_addr1:{
      type:'string'
  },

  mailing_addr2:{
      type:'string'
  },

  mailing_city:{
      type:'string'
  },

  mailing_state:{
      type:'string'
  },

  mailing_zip:{
      type:'string'
  },

  mailing_country:{
      type:'string'
  },

  primary_contact:{
      type:'string'
  },

  company_email:{
      type:'string',
      required:true,
      email:true
  },

  purchaser: {
      model: 'purchaseinfo'
  }

}

};
```

PurchaseInfo Controller

```
module.exports = {

  create: function(res, req){
  var purchaseData = req.params.all();

  // Extract the company info from the POSTed data
  var companyData = purchaseData.company_info;

 // Create the new Purchase record
  PurchaseInfo.create(purchaseData).exec(function(err,newPurchaseInfo){
      if (err){return res.req.serverError(err);}

      // Create the new Company, linking it to the purchase
      companyData.purchaser = newPurchaseInfo.id;
      Company.create(companyData).exec(function(err, newCompany) {
          if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
          return res.json(newPurchaseInfo);
      })
  })
},
_config: {}
};
```

POST

```
http://localhost:1337/purchaseinfo/create
body:
{   "parent_account": 1,    "purchase_date": "2014-03-03",  "product": "C V1",  "subscription_length": 12,  "renewal_date": "2015-03-03",   "users_authorized": 10,     "users_activated": 1,   "company_name": "Bob's Trucking",   "company_contact": "Jane Smith",    "company_email":"jsmith@bobstrucking.com",  "company_phone": 5035129657,    "intended_use": "trucking",     "company_info": {       "company_name": "Bob's Trucking",       "main_addr1": "101 First Street",       "main_city": "Portland",        "main_state": "OR",         "main_zip": "97230",        "main_country": "USA",      "mailing_same_as_main":"true",      "primary_contact": "Jane Smith",        "company_email": "info@bobstrucking.com"    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails v0.10 allows you to create *associations* between models.  Here's a quick example with `User` and `Pet` models:

```
/* api/models/User.js */
module.exports = {
   attributes: {
     name: 'string',
     pets: {
        collection: 'pet',
        via: 'owner'
     }
   }
};
```

---

```
/* api/models/Pet.js */
module.exports = {
   attributes: {
     name: 'string',
     breed: 'string',
     owner: {
        model: 'user'
     }
   }
};
```

---

```
/* api/controllers/UserController.js */
module.exports = {

  create: function(req, res) {

    // Assuming the POST contains all the data we need to create a user...
    var userData = req.params.all();
    // Extract the pet from the POSTed data
    var petData = userData.pet;
    // Delete the pet from the POSTed data, if you
    // don't want it saved to the User collection in Mongo
    delete userData.pet;
    // Create the new user
    User.create(userData).exec(function(err, newUser) {
       if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
       // Create the new pet, linking it to the user
       petData.owner = newUser.id;
       Pet.create(petData).exec(function(err, newPet) {
          if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
          return res.json(newUser);
       });

    });

  }
};
```

---

This code includes an override for the default `create` blueprint action for User; you could also create a separate controller action for it.  In reality you'd also probably want to check that the pet didn't already exist, do other validations, etc.  But this should get you on your way!

Comment: Scott, thank you for the oustanding reply!  I tried this and cannot get it to work yet.  I keep getting effectively "cannot read pet of undefined."  So it would appear that the body is not being parsed.  Also, I get errors on the "serverError" references.  Do those belong to Sails or are those your functions?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sorry, edited answer to specify that this is all in the latest version of Sails, which you can get [from Github](http://github.com/balderdashy/sails) or via `npm install sails@beta`. Although `res.serverError` should work in v0.9.x...

Comment: Also changed req.body to req.params.all(), which makes a hash of *all* the params sent to the route.

Comment: Fantastic!  I'll check this out tonight when I get home.  Thanks again!

Comment: With Scott's help I was able to get this working!  Thank you Scott.